# curl output to database

Tags: php

**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp)** which is used for output to a file. Is any way to set

output to database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. You will need to capture the output of the request as a string:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

and write code to store it in the database :)

Comment: +1ed - For a moment there I thought you were saying something different - funny how we say much the same thing but you answer the question "Yes", and I said "No"!

Answer (score 4):

No - send the output to a variable, and then insert the data in the variable to a database using `mysql_query`.

In general, inserting data into a database is a lot more complex than inserting data to a file (how do you connect to the database? what sort of database? what table? what column? update or insert? etc).